# SQL set column equal to another column from previous month for each unique value of separate column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

I apologize in advance for how complex this question seems, but this is what I'm dealing with.  I have a table with 5 million+ records in it. Of those 5 million+ records, I have about 185,000 unique values of what I'll call Column1. Column1 is a varchar field. I then have a date field that I'll call Column2 that is a date field ranging from '2005-01-01' to the current date. For each record, there is a float field that I'll call Column3.  Column3 holds the current rate for that particular record.  Then there is a different float field that I'll call Column4.  This field holds the last rate field that I need to set equal to whatever the value of Column3 was from the previous month that I'm getting from Column2. The tricky part is that I need to do this for each unique value of Column1. I hope that makes sense.  Right now all of my data in Column4 is null, but I want it to look like what you see below.

For example:

```
Column1      Column2      Column3      Column4
Record1      2005-01-01   6.25         6.25
Record2      2005-01-01   5.625        5.625
Record3      2005-01-01   4.75         4.75

Record1      2005-02-01   6.5          6.25
Record2      2005-02-01   5.625        5.625
Record3      2005-02-01   4.75         4.75

Record1      2005-03-01   6.75         6.5
Record2      2005-03-01   5.625        5.625
Record3      2005-03-01   5            4.75
```

As you can see, there are instances where the rate stays the same from month to month like with Record2.  However, there are times when it changes often like with Record1. And then there are other times when it only changes once like with Record3.  Please let me know your suggestions, and thank you in advance.

Comment: This is probably easier than you think. If you can provide some details we can help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The first 3 values in Column4 should be NULL since for them there's no previous record. Your task is pretty easy if you use window functions e.g. `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: @John Cowles_One question about `column2`: is it always `yyyy-MM-01`? If not, what should  `column4` be when `column2` is `2005-03-31` or `2005-03-30`, or `2005-01-02`?

Comment: @peter.petrov you are correct. For the sake of providing an example, I used those dates, but all of the values in '2005-01-01' will end up being NULL when I'm done.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach That date will always be on the first of the month.  I run another update statement that hard codes the value to be the first of the month.  So there will never be an instance of -2005-03-30 or 2005-01-02 in the database.

Comment: "that I'll call" is a bit long winded -  just post a table design

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a self left join to get the previous value like this:

```
declare @t table (column1 varchar(10), column2 datetime, column3 float, column4 float)

insert into @t (column1, column2, column3)
select 'RecordA', '2005-01-01', 6.25 union all
select 'RecordB', '2005-01-01', 5.625 union all
select 'RecordC', '2005-01-01', 4.75 union all
select 'RecordA', '2005-02-01', 6.5 union all
select 'RecordB', '2005-02-01', 5.625 union all
select 'RecordC', '2005-02-01', 4.75 union all
select 'RecordA', '2005-03-01', 6.75 union all
select 'RecordB', '2005-03-01', 5.625 union all
select 'RecordC', '2005-03-01', 5

update cur
set column4 = pre.column3 
from @t as cur
left join @t as pre on
    cur.column1 = pre.column1 and
    dateadd(mm, -1, cur.column2) = pre.column2 


select * 
from @t 
order by column2, column1
```

Comment: Bear with me because this is my first time posting on Stack Overflow...I copied and pasted your code and it worked exactly how I wanted it to. The problem I'm experiencing however is that there are 185,000 unique records. So it's more than just RecordA, RecordB, RecordC...there's also RecordD, RecordE, RecordF, etc.  Perhaps if I gave it a different naming convention it would make more sense. Think of those records as Record1, Record2, and Record3. The last record would be Record185000. There's no way I can hardcore all of those values for each record. Does this additional info help?

Comment: @JohnCowles - I was just posting an example with sample data. All you need to do is use the code that starts with `update` and replace `@t` with your actual table name

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I did what you said and I believe it worked. Still going to do some validation on my end, but I think you've solved my headache. Thank you very much!